# url_for not working for Javascript file in HTML

Tags: python, flask

Hopefully, I'm missing something simple here but when I run the following HTML code through Flask the Javascript file fails to run. When I put my Javascript code from my file inline: `alert('boo')`, it works fine, so my Javascript code isn't the issue. The javascript file is indeed in my static folder and the names match, also the issue is the same on multiple browsers.

No error is shown and the HTML page loads normally as though there is no Javascript/it is ignoring it.

EDIT - There is an error, I was only looking in terminal. In the browser console it says **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier** and highlights my src.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script> type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename='javascripts.js')}}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _“No error is shown”_ - where did you look …? If the generated path was incorrect, then you should see a 404 or something in the browser console, or network panel at least. Have you at least checked the resulting HTML, and verified you got the path you were _expecting_ there?

Comment: You have a typo, you close the script tag before the type attribute  `<script> type="text/javascript"` You can omit the type attribute

Comment: Change to `<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='javascripts.js')}}"></script>
`

Comment: Feel free to delete the question. It is not useful for anyone but you

Comment: [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

Answer (score -1):

Okay, it's sorted now. My mistake was thinking the url_for had to be in between the script tags instead of apart of the tag. The working code is.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename='javascripts.js')}}"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, I told you 20 minutes ago :)